# How to limit content width in a superwide screen without media query

Tags: css, css-grid

I was wondering if I could use css-grid or something as simple to limit the width of my content in a superwide screen but then allow it to show full width in smaller screens.

I don't want to use media queries.

Here is my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/to29jhm1/)

My idea is something like

```
grid-template-columns: minmax(1fr, 40em);
```

But this is invalid css.  Is there something valid and equivalent?

Comment: Just centring an element with a max-width is the old way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One very simple way is to just centre an element with a `width: 100%` and a `max-width`:

```css
#example {
  background-color: #009;
  width: 100%;            /* Fill 100% width */
  max-width: 1000px;      /* Unless it's larger than the maximum */
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="example"></div>
```

(Click the "Full page" snippet button to see this working)